# Can I prevent some route to be rendered on server side in React App

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

I am going to use server side rendering for my react app to improve the website's SEO. Therefore, letting some pages to be rendered on server is important for me. However, I do not want to have the rest pages (nested routes) to be rendered on server side though. Can I have both client and server side rendering with different routes (and routes' config) at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using different router config - you will get react warning because of the html miss match.

to solve this you can switch your router into something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class RouterHandler extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isShow: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isShow: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isShow } = this.state;
    const { component, ...props } = this.props;
    if (isShow) {
      return <Route {...props} component={component} />;
    }
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}
```

and use it instead of you `<Router>` inside `<Switch>`

this will work because `componentDidMount` is only called on client side.

using code chunking user wont see the diffrence.

Comment: I’m using react-router-config though. Therefore, I use routes as objects instead of <Route/>. Can I still use your approach ?

Comment: You can make it into a HOC (Higher-Order Component), and wrap routes you dont want to render on the server.